# How to make your code not compilable if its format does not math some rules?

Tags: formatting, compiler-errors

How to make your code not compilable if its format does not match some rules?
For example (C# language):

```
if (a < b)
{
                  // <-- build error with message "empty line"
     k = j + h;
}
```

or

```
public void Method(int a, int name) // <-- build error with message "parameter name 'a' is too short"
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This kind of stuff is more like "advice" than strict requirement and has nothing to do with the C# compilation process. Looks like you want a code inspection tool or something like that.

Comment: BTW, why would an empty line be an error?  Empty lines are useful for indicating sections of code.

Comment: If you prevent your user from using blank lines to format their code, then your tool is pretty much useless.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson, does not compute, leave now you are working for people who care about whether the code meets their definition of pretty, as opposed to being readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking specifically for C# style-checking, have you tried [stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)?

For a comprehensive list of style-checkers, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the compiler has specific flags to reject certain types of syntax, you can't make the compiler do that. But you can add a code analysis script that analyzes the source code prior to compiling. You can implement all kinds of coding style rules in that script and it will reject the source code before actually compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your version control system reject a checkin if it doesn't conform to standards.